# Ruby: hexadecimal in regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, hex

I need to match an md5 checksum in a regular expression in a Ruby (actually Rails) program. I found out somewhere that I can match hexadecimal strings with `\h` sequence, but I can't find the link anymore.

I'm using that sequence and my code is working in Ruby 1.9.2. I can make it working even under plain IRB (so it's not a Rails extension).

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > "123abcdf" =~ /^\h+$/; $~
 => #<MatchData "123abcdf"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > "123abcdfg" =~ /^\h+$/; $~
 => nil
```

However my IDE mark that expression as wrong and I can't find any reference which cites that sequence.

Is the `\h` sequence legal in Ruby Regex under any environment/version or should I trust my ide and replace it with something like `[abcdef\d]`?

Comment: You should check for /\A\h+\Z/ see http://sakurity.com/blog/2015/06/04/mongo_ruby_regexp.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is. Check [the official doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) for the complete documentation for regex in Ruby.

Note that `\h` will match uppercase letters too, so it's actually equivalent to `[a-fA-F\d]`

Comment: One small note - it will also match integers, so the whole class is [a-fA-Z0-9].

Comment: @jdc: `\d` is same as `[0-9]`

Comment: The link to "this SO answer" no longer works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160739/where-is-rubys-regexp-behavior-documented/6563990#6563990.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions) \h is part of oniguruma, which I believe is standard in ruby 1.9.